# Send native message without running new process

Tags: c++, linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, stdin

How I can send message from google chrome extensions without running new process?
I create example extensions with [Port](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-Port) and [without Port](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendNativeMessage)

But when I sent message to my application, extensions is starting new process

http://blog.chromium.org/2013/10/connecting-chrome-apps-and-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

Either way chrome is going to start at least **one** process,but with the 'Port' choice it will start 1 process only.If you call more than one

```
 chrome.extension.connectNative('com.company.com');
```

it will create a process every time.
Both of the functions, *chrome.extension.connectNative* and  *chrome.extension.sendNativeMessage* will make Chrome create a process when they are called,the difference is the first expects the process to stay alive for maybe more than one message.